# automake: distcheck with CPPFLAGS

Tags: automake

I am looking for something like DISTCHECK_CONFIGURE_FLAGS but more flexible.

I am using an external package in my program.  Let's say `foo` and on my laptop it's installed to `${HOME}/soft/foo`.

configuring with the autotools is simple:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS=-I${HOME}/soft/foo/include LDFLAGS=-L${HOME}/soft/foo/lib
```

but `distcheck` is giving me headaches.  When distcheck unpacks and configures, how do I tell it to use my CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS?

`DISTCHECK_CONFIGURE_FLAGS` is close, but incorrect: other maintainers might have the `foo` library installed under `/opt/` or `/software/random/whatever` or `/usr/local/foo-master` and I don't want to impose my environment on other maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to not hard-code anything in the Makefile.am.  Automake will inherit several environment variables from autoconf.

All one needs to do is pass the `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` used to configure the package:

```
DISTCHECK_CONFIGURE_FLAGS = CPPFLAGS=${CPPFLAGS} CFLAGS=${CFLAGS}\
     ${CXXFLAGS}=${CXXFLAGS} LDFLAGS=${LDFLAGS}
```

and now 'make distcheck' will use the requested flags and find the headers and libraries for the desired package.

Comment: I would add that you should probably pass through `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` as well.